# Adding/removing variables to PCA

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

If I have a PCA that I ran on some set of variables, how (if at all) will it relate to the PCA results if I add or remove one variable?

Will the PCA components change in some well-defined way, or is there no relationship that is guaranteed between the old and new eigenvalues & eigenvectors?

Comment: The variable you mean here is the number of observation or the dimension of the data?

Comment: The dimension of the data

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee - it depends on the distribution of the added / removed variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/180424)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The question was whether there is a guaranteed relationship between the old and new PCA. The answer is that there is no guaranteed relationship. This is not a critique, it is simply the answer.